# Python: setting a string so it always has 2 decimals after comma

Tags: python-3.x, string

I'm looking to write a Python function that adds a number to the back of the string. However, I want it in a way that the string always has 2 characters after the comma.

I believe using a string is easier to remove and skip characters. I will be converting the result with the `float()` method.

As an example:

I start at the string `"0.00"`

Adding a 5 will make it `"0.05"`
Adding a 5 and a 6 will make it `"5.56"` etc

Another example:

again we start at `"0.00"`. Adding consecutive the characters `"5"` `"4"` `"3"` `"2"` `"1"` will ultimately result in `"543.21"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just convert the string to an integer and divide the number by 100?

```
num = int(input())
print(num/float(100))

E.g. input = '5',
     convert to integer = 5,
     Divide by 100 = 0.05
```

Comment: Oh I was completely thinking I had to write some complicated string altering algorithm. I totally forgot about using simple math. Thanks